# MPMoviePlayerViewController Subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, statusbar, subview

I have a view within my view controller and have it declared as a property _movieSubview. I add a MPMoviePlayerViewController to _movieSubview and the video plays nicely.

```
-(void)moviePlay{


NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"High Rope" ofType:@"mov"]];
_playerController=[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
//[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:_playerController];
_playerController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

[_playerController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
_playerController.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
_playerController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
_playerController.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
[_playerController.moviePlayer play];


/*[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:_playerController];*/
//---play partial screen---
_playerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
[_movieSubview addSubview:_playerController.view];

}

- (void)moviePlayerDidFinish:(NSNotification *)note
{
    if (note.object == _playerController) {
        NSInteger reason = [[note.userInfo     objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] integerValue];
        if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded)
        {
            [_playerController.moviePlayer play];
        }
    }
}
```

My 2 questions are:

1. My status bar disappears when I add the MPMoviePlayerViewController inside my subview. How do I keep the status bar?
2. How can I have the video play twice on repeat, then wait for user to play after that?

Comment: Update ur question with ur code. if possible , with screen shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should present _playerController instead of adding as subview. Use this code while creating the instance of MPMoviePlayer:

```
     [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
     moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;

     NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
     [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerEvent:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:moviePlayer];
     [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(playBackStateChanged:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:moviePlayer];

    -(void)moviePlayerEvent:(NSNotification*)aNotification{

          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:NO];

    }

   -(void)playBackStateChanged:(id)sender{
MPMoviePlaybackState playbackState = [moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer playbackState];

switch (playbackState) {

    case MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped :

        //play again
        NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [notificationCenter removeObserver:self]; 
        break;

    case MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying :
        break;

    case MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted :
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to show my video in small screen (embedded screen). how ithe code will be?

Comment: The reason for wanting to put my player in a subview was to play partial screen and have other labels/buttons around it. Is there a way to do this without subview?

Comment: Check with replacing this code 
          _playerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
to
          _playerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460);

Comment: No that didn't help because the video is already within the frame of the subview, but I see what you were thinking.